# Append two regressions in one simple column with stargazer

Tags: r, regression, stargazer

I would like to use stargazer adding a new regression but I'm not want add a new column, but that were in the same column. I tried to do some replicable example:

```
reg1 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + factor(am), data = mtcars)

reg2 <- lm(mpg ~ wt + factor(gear), data = mtcars)

stargazer::stargazer(reg1,reg2,
                     title="Results", align=TRUE , digits = 3,out="table2.tex",append=T,
                      keep = c("am","gear"))
```

Current output

[image: My stargazer output]

Desired output:

[image: How I wish were]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do this with any specific parameter with `stargazer`, so you will have to modify your LaTeX code [manually](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28093/192122).